# Syntax Error In jsp form: var isError = <h:outputText value="#{billpayuploadbean.m_bError}" />;

Tags: html, jsp, jsf, jsf-2.2, taglib

I have used this syntax in JSP form but it showing uncaught syntax error.
Library used: *jsf-api-2.2.9.jar*

```
var isError = <h:outputText value="#{billpayuploadbean.m_bError}" />;
```

After importing these two lines:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="f" uri="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="h" uri="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"%>
```

It showing resource does not exist on the server.

This is upgrading project.
before that this syntax running but now it's not working in our product.
before that *jsf-api.jar* file used and now *jsf-api-2.2.9.jar* file used.

Comment: You should use the syntax of JavaScript. This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Comment: error is: The tag handler class for "h:outputText" (com.sun.faces.taglib.html_basic.OutputTextTag) was not found on the Java Build Path

Comment: Add the taghandler to the Java Build Path.

Comment: where do I get that tag handler?

Comment: I have added these 4 jar files: jsf-api-2.2.9.jar, jsf-impl-2.2.9, servlet-api.jar, tomahawk-1.1.14.jar

Comment: Did you find a taghandler in these libraries? If there's no taghandler in them or version mismatch then you cant't use a tag.

Comment: I got one thing,  before that jsf-api.jar, jsf-impl.jar, jsp-api.jar, servlet-api.jar these 4 jar files were used but now i am using jsf-api-2.2.9.jar, jsf-impl-2.2.9.jar, jsp-api.jar, servlet-api.jar these 4 jar files. Before that its worked but now its now working because we haved changed 2 jar files. which Jar files version would suitable for jsf-api-2.2.9.jar and jsf-impl-2.2.9.jar?

Comment: Tag handler is available in jsp-api.jar but this jar is not working with jsf-api-2.2.9.jar version.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase.setJspId(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.jsp.CustomWorkList.BillPay_005fWork_0020Introduction_jsp._jspx_meth_h_005foutputText_005f0(BillPay_005fWork_0020Introduction_jsp.java:168)
 at org.apache.jsp.CustomWorkList.BillPay_005fWork_0020Introduction_jsp._jspService(BillPay_005fWork_0020Introduction_jsp.java:114)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:791)

Answer (score 0):

converted form .jsp to .xhtml, it works